# How to make parent container as big as children?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a table out of divs. The reason to why I'm using divs is a table might not be as responsive as I want.

Anyways I made this container that should be the width of the children and centered, however for some reason it decides to be bigger despite no width being set. Any ideas on how to fix that?

```css
.wrapper {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  margin-left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}

.wrapper div {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0; height: 100vh; width: 100vw;">
  <section class="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: remove `float:left` ? and add `min-height:100%` in wrapper  like here->https://jsfiddle.net/fdkkbj5e/

Comment: Maybe use `overflow-x: scroll;` for .wrapper?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `display: table | table-row | table-cell;` to create your `<div>` table?

Comment: I am not sure about him, but man, I have had some really weird crap happen when using :table | table-row | table-cell. Could be entirely me, but I don't usually get the expected behavior in all browsers.

Comment: @VikingBlooded I don't have an issue using them at all. So [this doesn't work](https://jsfiddle.net/7ztojxpy/2) for you?

Comment: @hungerstar sometimes does, I think it's more of an issue with having to override boostrap more than I like.

Comment: @VikingBlooded using a third party framework and having issues with using `display: table | table-row | table-cell;` to create _"DIV tables"_ is a completely different issue than suggesting there's cross-browser issues in general (first statement). When using third party CSS, style collisions are a concern and something one would have to deal with if it happens (second statement). But if that's not the case (third party styles or not) then _"DIV tables"_  [should work fine](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table).

Answer (score 4):

It's your floats. If you want the container to "contain" the divs, you have to "float" bu either using float on the container itself or using inline block.

I would suggest using `display:inline-block`

Try this out:

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: purple;
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 280px;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper div {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

This will cause your container to actually contain the elements within it. Additionally, you will need to add the max-width to the container to ensure you don't have any wonky padding to the right. You might want to use some media queries to set that up so that it looks right at each size.

```
@media screen AND (max-width: 300px) {
    .wrapper {
        max-width: 280px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that all children of your `.wrapper` div are floating, resulting in a height of 0 on their parent. You can simply remedy this by setting `overflow:hidden` on the wrapping container, if you need them to be floating (you could also use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left` and wouldn't require the overflow property).

```css
.wrapper {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  margin-left: 50%;
  background-color: purple;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper div {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0; height: 100vh; width: 100vw;">
  <section class="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: As usual, an explanation on the downvote would ge good, especially considering it's the only one in the thread explaining why that error occurs...

Answer (score 2):

Set the wrapper div to display: inline-block;

HTML

```
  <section class="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: purple;
}

.wrapper div {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/frankspin/pen/vKbBoJ)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address your specific code, but you did mention trying to create tables with DIVs. You could use `display: table | table-row | table-cell;`.

Here's one way to implement it:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}
.tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.td {
  display: table-cell;
}
.example {
  width: 50%;
}
.example .td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="table example">

  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="td">
      B
    </div>
    <div class="td">
      C
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">
      D
    </div>
    <div class="td">
      E
    </div>
    <div class="td">
      F
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

You could also change up the CSS to what's below if you didn't want to slap a CSS class onto every element:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}
.table > div {
  display: table-row;
}
.table > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
```